# Reshaping data in R with time values in column names

Tags: r, database, statistics, reshape

I have a data frame which looks like this (simplified):

```
     data1.time1 data1.time2 data2.time1 data2.time2 data3.time1 group
 1          1.53        2.01        6.49        5.22        3.46    A
 ...
 24         2.12        3.14        4.96        4.89        3.81    C
```

where there are actually `dataK.timeT` for K in 1..27 and T in some (but maybe not all) of 1..8.

I would like to rearrange the data into K data frames so that I can plot, for each K, the summary data (for now let's say mean and mean ± standard deviation) for each of the three groups A, B, and C. That is, I want 27 graphs with three lines per graph, and also marks for the deviations.

Once I rearrange the data it should be easy enough to collapse by group, compute summary statistics, etc. But I'm not really sure how to get the data into this form. I looked at the `reshape` package, which suggests melting it into a key-value store format and rearranging from there, but it doesn't seem to support the columns containing the T values as I have here.

Is there a good way to do this? I'm quite willing to use something other than R to do this, since I can just import the results into R after transforming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After creating fake data with a structure similar to yours, we convert from wide to long format, making a "tidy" data frame that is ready for plotting with `ggplot2`.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
```

#### Create fake data

```
set.seed(194)
dat = data.frame(replicate(27*8, cumsum(rnorm(24*3))))

names(dat) = paste0(rep(paste0("data",1:27), each=8), ".", rep(paste0("time",1:8), 27))

dat$group = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=24)
```

Remove some columns so that number of time points will be different for different data sources:

```
dat = dat[ , -c(2,4,9,43,56,78,100:103,115:116,134:136,202,205)]
```

#### Reshape from wide to long format

```
datl = melt(dat, id.var="group")
```

Split data source and time point into separate columns:

```
datl$source = gsub("(.*)\\..*","\\1", datl$variable)
datl$time = as.numeric(gsub(".*time(.*)","\\1", datl$variable))

# Order data frame names by number (rather than alphabetically)
datl$source = factor(datl$source, levels=paste0("data",1:length(unique(datl$source))))
```

#### Plot the data using ggplot2

```
# Helper function for plotting standard deviation
sdFnc = function(x) {
  vals = c(mean(x) - sd(x), mean(x) + sd(x))
  names(vals) = c("ymin", "ymax")
  vals
}

pd = position_dodge(0.7)

ggplot(datl, aes(time, value, group=group, color=group)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", position=pd) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=sdFnc, geom="errorbar", width=0.4, position=pd) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", position=pd) +
  facet_wrap(~source, ncol=3) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Original (unnecessarily complicated) reshaping code. (Note, this code will no longer work with the updated (fake) data set, because the number of time columns is no longer uniform):

```
# Convert data source from wide to long
datl = data.frame()
for (i in seq(1,27*8,8)) {

  tmp.dat = dat[, c(i:(i+7),grep("group",names(dat)))]
  tmp.dat$source = gsub("(.*)\\..*", "\\1", names(tmp.dat)[1])
  names(tmp.dat)[1:8] = 1:8

  #datl = rbind(datl, tmp.dat)
  datl = bind_rows(datl, tmp.dat)  # Updated based on comment
}

datl$source = factor(datl$source, levels=paste0("data",1:27))

# Convert time from wide to long
datl = melt(datl, id.var = c("source","group"), variable.name="time")
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! There is a slight problem, though: as in the original question, not all entries have 8 members. I changed the `tmp.dat` inner loop to account for this, but when I `rbind` I get I get a "numbers of columns of arguments do not match" error. Should I just fill with `NA`, maybe?

Comment: Use `bind_rows` from the `dplyr` package instead of `rbind`. `bind_rows` stacks columns by name, not by index position, so you don't have to worry about whether data frames have the same columns or whether the columns are in the same order. It also fills with `NA` for missing values automatically.

Comment: See updated code. I realized I was making the reshaping unnecessarily complicated. New version doesn't require `rbind` or `bind_rows` and automatically accounts for any number time columns for each data source.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, much better than I deserved. Thank you for being so thorough -- I learned a lot from this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Could do something like this with dplyr:

```
for(i in 1:K){ ## for 1:27
  my.data.ind <- paste0("data",i,"|group") ## "datai|group"
  one.month <- select(data, contains(my.data.ind) %>% ## grab cols that have these
                  group_by(group) %>% ## group by your group
                  summarise_each(funs(mean), funs(sd)) ## find mean for each col within each group
}
```

That should leave you with a 3xT data frame that has the average value of each group over time T

Comment: What is `%>%`? I've seen it before but it's hard to search for.

Comment: This is a "chaining" operator that allows you to string functions one after another. The output of the previous operation is fed into the next one. The operator is used in `dplyr`, but is actually imported from the `magrittr` package. See the help page (`?"%>%"`) for more info.

Comment: Yes -- I didn't know I needed quotes, but at least I had tried. :)